# Remove the last letter of every String in Array [JAVA]

Tags: java, arrays, stringbuffer

As the title says.

In want to remove the last letter of every word in an array and put it to the beginning of every word.

Here's an example (Input):

```
Hello I am a player
```

And here's the output:

```
oHell I ma a rplaye
```

I tried:

```
StringBuffer lastChar = new StringBuffer(output);
lastChar.deleteCharAt(lastChar.length()-1);
System.out.println(lastChar);
```

But it will just remove the last char of the String and won't put it to the beginning.
AND does it only for a whole sentence and not for every word individually.

Love your help here!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a one liner:

```
str = Arrays.stream(str.split(" "))
    .map(s -> s.replaceAll("(.*)(.)", "$2$1"))
    .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```

The main operation is `replaceAll("(.*)(.)", "$2$1")` which captures all but the last characters as group 1, and the last char as group 2, and replaces the entire string with group 2 then group 1, effectively "moving" the last char to the front.

Comment: I will try it. Give me a second.

Answer (score 0):

First, we must parse the string into its words. We can do this with

```
String[] words = input.split(" ");
```

After we have an array of words, we just have to loop through it and modify each element.

```
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    String word = words[i];
    String lastChar = word.substring(word.length() - 1);
    words[i] = lastChar + word.substring(0, word.length() - 1);
}
```

Finally, we have to recombine the array into a single string.

```
String result = String.join(" ", words);
```

Comment: I do get errors with the code.
https://imgur.com/a/0jK0BJy

Comment: Should be ````words.length```` not ````length()````. And rename lastChar because there are two variables declared with that name

Comment: Also you appear to have renamed ````words```` to ````arrayOfStr````. So you'll have to replace words with arrayOfStr

Comment: Also you don't need ````newArrOfStr```` you can replace it with ````arrOfStr```` and delete the loop you added..

Comment: works now. I'll try it quick

Comment: Anyway just use @Bohemian's code it is more concise

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Pattern PAT = Pattern.compile("(\\w*)(\\w)");
String input = "Hello I am a player";
String output = PAT.matcher(input).replaceAll(m -> m.group(2) + m.group(1));
System.out.println(output);
```

output:

```
oHell I ma a rplaye
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split it into words and then rotate the characters in each word using `Collections.rotate()`:

```
String rotate(String word) {
    String[] chars = word.split("");
    Collections.rotate(Arrays.asList(chars), 1);
    return String.join("", chars);
}
```

[**Ideone Demo**](https://ideone.com/j6TcXa)